# $inc throwing exception with findByIdAndUpdate in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, server

Hello here is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b2d706f61d04e8d99dd983"),
    "userName" : "a",
    "password" : "v",
    "addresses" : {
        "info" : {
            "count" : {
                "userAddress" : 0,
                "vendorAddress" : 0
            }
        },
        "user" : [],
        "vendor" : []
    }
}
```

Now I want to **push one address** in **vendor sub-document array** and **increase the vendorAddress count by 1**, in one go with respect to the object Id **57b2d706f61d04e8d99dd983**

So for doing that I have used the following code with mongoose:

```
usersModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  vendorId,
  {
        "$push" : {
          "addresses.vendor" : address
        },
        $inc : {
          "addresses.info.count.vendorAddress" : 1 //--------->(A)
        }
  },
  {
        "new": true,
        "select" : {
          "addresses.vendor" : 1
        }
  },
  function(error, list){
        //can return the new doc and all
  }
);
```

Suppose my address is a json with address of the vendor, then this thing is generating the exception as:

```
exception: '$inc' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$inc: {<field>: ...}}
```

But of I remove the line of (A) and rerun the program with the same input it succeeds. Now my doubt is why, although the thing is pretty neat and straight forward.

Please shed some views.
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for supporting on this question, and I have found the bug, actually my schema definition had a bug and the bug was like this:

```
var _info = new Schema({ //---------->(A)
  "_id" : false, // ------------> (B)
  "addresses" : {
    "count" : {
      "vendorAddress" : Number
    }
  }
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  "userName" : String,
  "password" : String,
  "info" : _info,
  "addresses" : {
    "vendor" : [_vendorAddresses] //----> (C)
  }
});
```

***FYI: _vendorAddresses had a perfect Schema.***

Now the problem was the equation (A) and (B), so I have debugged it and found I have being creating a new object since it is new Schema as per equation (A). So I removed those 2 lines and found that it is now working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should go with `update` query instead of `findByIdAndUpdate`

```
usersModel.update({"_id" : ObjectId("57b2d706f61d04e8d99dd983")}, {   $push:{"addresses.vendor":address},   $inc : {"addresses.info.count.vendorAddress" : 1}  });
```

Comment: Whats the difference in that?